# Chrome HTML notifications not executing JavaScript

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I'm working on a Chrome extension that uses the notificaions API.  I'm wanting to use an HTML notification to build a link but I need to make some callbacks to the background page for data.  My problem is none of my JavaScript is executing in the notification page.  I know it's possible because I use other extensions that do this.  Is there something special I need to do to enable this, say something in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is make sure a jQuery plug-in file you're using isn't corrupted.